# What is the this error code in VS code (node:14688)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

(node:14688) [INSPECTOR_ASYNC_STACK_TRACES_NOT_AVAILABLE] Warning: Warning: Async stack traces in debugger are not available on 32bit platforms. The feature is disabled.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la2St.png)

Not sure what needs to be done, had issues with npm install and other issues but I fixed that now Now I have this issue it seems like I fix an issue just to get another. Theres no search results for this in google. Do i need to install something else or is it a path issue?

Comment: So are you running a 32bit system or 64?

Comment: its a warning not an error, you installed the 32 bit version of node, remove it and install the 64 bit version https://nodejs.org/en/download

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying I do have a 64bit but I guess it downloaded the 32bit version. I'll make the switch.